# Finding a difficult sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

This question comes from U-Chicago's GRE practice tests. Weeks one, problem 6.

Find the sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{3^n}$$
I want to use the derivative trick starting with the obvious,
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \Rightarrow \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$
Then, letting $x=3$, we can work our way to the fact,
$$\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(1-2/3)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n} $$
I'd like to somehow use this to find the desired sum. It seems like I should be really close from here, but I'm not sure how to get to $n^2$. Any advice?

Comment: Hint: differentiate a second time.

Comment: Hint to the hint: Multiply by x before you differentiate the second time. :-)

Comment: Not necessarily :-). My idea was rather (like in the accepted answer of the duplicate) to first find the closed formulas for $\sum nx^{n-1}$ and $\sum n(n-1)x^{n-2}$, and then combine them to get $\sum n^2x^n.$ Anyway, this is a multiduplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval - Yeah, that's how I learned to do it too. I just think it's spiffier if you fix things up while taking the derivatives so you land on the exact formula you wanted. But like you say, it's a mega-dup. Thanks for searching up one and taking care of the closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the first derivative by $x$, take a derivative of the whole result and you will have a sum with $n^2$. Then just plug in $x=\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: For such a FAQ, better link to one of the many duplicates than edit an answer.